# does the jasperreports server (community edition) have etl?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I just downloaded  jasperreports server (community edition) which uses postgresql. (there is no option to install using a mysql database). All my databases are using mysql server. The question is does the community edition of jasperreports server have ETL as an embedded functionality since jaspersoft etl is available as a separate download?

If not does this mean I have to convert all the mysql databases to use the postgresql server?

Rumbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and you don't need to convert. You can in fact install JasperServer in MySQL though, I'm just not sure if you can do it with the standard installer or if you have to make modifications. But only the JasperServer data is stored in the postgresql db(JRXML files, jasperserver credentials, etc.) you can certainly still build reports off of your MySQL databases and would not have to convert them to postgresql.

Here is a post someone wrote about installing JasperServer on MySQL 5.5 - [link](http://www.foscode.com/installing-jasperserver40-mysql55/)

EDIT: The current version (Sept 2015) JasperReports Community Edition does have ETL now [download link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/download) It is a modified form of Talend Data Integrations.

Comment: Edit is required in this answer; JasperReports Community Edition does have ETL now http://community.jaspersoft.com/download It is a modified form of Talend Data Integrations.

Answer (score 1):

Ben's answer was completely correct... but it's a bit misleading because JasperReports Server Community Edition 4.5 now fully supports MySQL 5.5. The post he links to was very helpful, but it's no longer needed with JRS 4.5.

On the [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperServer%204.5.0/) choose "jasperreports-server-cp-4.5.0-bin.zip". (Don't choose the installers that bundle in PostgreSQL.) You'll find the section 6.1.2 Manually Creating the JasperReports Server Database - MySQL in the included document "JasperReports-Server-CP-Install-Guide.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper Reports Server 5.5 we can add the required driver from the "JDBC Driver" dropdown list in the select datasource page. There the required driver can be added; in this case "MYSQL(com.mysql.jdbc.driver)"